# Automatically get the user’s location from the user’s browser instead of hard-coding in django view to filter nearest shop

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, geodjango

Am building a simple nearby shops application that lists the shops closest to a user’s location using django and GeoDjango. To list the shops, i want to get a user's location from their browser and then filter the nearest shop for the user instead of hard-coding it.

**views.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from .models import Shop

longitude = -80.191_788
latitude = 25.761_681

user_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)


class Home(generic.ListView):
    model = Shop
    context_object_name = "shops"
    queryset = Shop.objects.annotate(
        distance=Distance("location", user_location)
    ).order_by("distance")[0:6]
    template_name = "Home.html"
```

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: You better ask a question about javascript or about how to get location from browser by js . Not about python and Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API services like Google Places API to give you data on nearby objects as well as the current location using the geolocating call within the API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview